# Amenability for Actions twited with 2-cocycles

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, group-actions, amenability, crossed-products

Let $A \subset B(H)$ be a unital $C^\ast$-algebra and $\theta: G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ an action and let $\omega: G \times G \rightarrow U(\mathcal{Z}(A))$ be a $2$-cocyle with respect to $\theta$ taking values in the unitary group of the center of $A$, i.e. a function satisfying
$$
  \omega(g,h) \, \omega(g h, k) = \theta_g(\omega(h,k)) \, \omega(g, hk).
$$
We can define the twisted (reduced) crossed product $A \rtimes_{(\theta, \omega)} G \subset B(L_2(G;H))$ as the smallest $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $A$, embedded inside $B(L_2(G;H))$ like in the case of crossed products, and the unitaries $\{u_g\}_{g \in G}$ which act by
$$
  (u_g \xi)(h) = \omega(h^{-1}, g) \, \xi(g^{-1} h),
$$
for $\xi \in L_2(G;H)$. Similarly we can define a full/universal crossed product $A \rtimes_{(\theta, \omega)}^{ full} G$ by taking the supremum over all representation preserving the multiplication law
$$
  (x \, u_g) \, (y \, u_h) = x \, \theta_g(y) \, \omega(g,h) \, u_{g \, h}.
$$
What can be said on the amenability of $A \rtimes_{\theta, \omega} G$? In particular.

> **Question 1.:** Is there any definition of amenability for $(\theta,\omega)$ in the literature satisfying that, if $(\theta,\omega)$ is amenable, then
>
> 1. $A \rtimes_{(\theta, \omega)} G$ is nuclear whenever $A$ is.
> 2. $A \rtimes_{(\theta, \omega)} G = A \rtimes_{(\theta, \omega)}^{full} G$

> **Question 2.:** Is that notion of amenability equal to the amenability of $\theta$? (in the sense of [1, Definition 4.3.1]) Or, by the contrary, can an amenable action have nonnuclear twisted crossed products?

[1] Brown, Ozawa. $C^\ast$-Algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations.

Comment: Question 1 is answered in Proposition 25.10 in [this book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04565).

Comment: Regarding question 2, I suppose there is no harm in assuming that $\omega(1,g)=\omega(g,1)=1$, in which case a Cesaro net ([Definition 20.4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04565)) for the crossed product is also a Cesaro net for the twisted version, so the answer to the first part of question 2 is also affirmative.